# Make cell color the same as another cell color and keep formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, colors, conditional-formatting

In Excel 2007, I've conditional formatting for column Q:

- values > -5 = green
- values between -5 and -25 are yellow and
- values less than -25 are red.

I want cell P5 to have the same color as Q5, Cell P6 to have the same color as Q6 and so forth.

The value in cell P5 is dependent on a formula (K5-C5),
the value in cell P6 is dependent on a formula (K6-C6) and so forth.

How can I change the color of the cells in column P so they are equal to their "matching" cells in column Q, without ruining the formulas created in column P?

Comment: What has VBA got to do with this?

Comment: If it can be solved without VBA, great. It's just that the closest I've come to a solution has been via VBA.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly then you do not need vba for this. See the answer that I posted. You may have to refresh the page...

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, then you don't need VBA for this. Simply highlight the relevant range and not just column Q while conditional formatting. See this example

[image]

Comment: Hmm I wrote what you said: =AND($Q5<>"",$Q5>-5) but I get a warning saying that the formula I've typed contains an error? I've tried both to highlight the complete range and only one cell, but I get an error no matter what.

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of what have you done? Like I way I have shown you?

Comment: Sure but how? It says I need 10 reputation points to post a picture?

Comment: Just upload to a free file sharing site and share the link here.

Comment: Ok Thanks :) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xaw00gafk45qkic/AAAaITrF_Hw6ho93ahZm9E1ua?dl=0

Comment: You screenshot looks ok to me. The data starts from row 5 so `=AND($Q5<>"",$Q5>-5)` is correct. May I see your file?

Comment: Try and clear all formatting rule from that range and try again?

Comment: I've tried to clear all formatting rules, but still the same error. I've uploaded an excel file for you to see.

Comment: To the same link as before:) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xaw00gafk45qkic/AAAaITrF_Hw6ho93ahZm9E1ua?dl=0

Comment: Sorry. Got distracted. Looking at it now.

Comment: It is working on my pc. In the sample file that you gave, the data started from row 4, so the formula I used was `=AND($Q4<>"",$Q4>-5)`

Answer (score 0):

I have not bothered with cutoffs since for example you have not specified the formatting you required for a cell in ColumnQ with value `-5`.

For consistency with the details in your link, I have assumed that the likes of `values >-5` refer to `-5%` rather than `-5`.

To change the color of the cells in column P so they are equal to their "matching" cells in column Q, without ruining the formulas created in column P apply Conditional Formatting (which does not alter the actual cell content, only its appearance).

To format ColumnP cells according to rules determined by ColumnQ cells adjust the range to which the formatting is applied. Roughly, determine the format for Q and apply that to P:Q.

Since three colours are involved CF will require at least two rules where determined by formulae (a third colour could be applied by 'standard' fill, which CF rules override).

Formula rules as below appear to meet my limited understanding of your requirements:

Green: `=$Q4>-0.05`
Yellow: `=AND($Q4>-0.25,$Q4<0.05)`
Red: `=$Q4<0.25`

For the example I chose the applicable range for each as:

```
=$P$4:$Q$12
```

[image: SO26714147 example]

Note:

1. These do not directly address transition values such as -5%
2. Empty cells will also be formatted
3. The order of the rules makes a difference